# Rust macro error: local ambiguity: multiple parsing options

Tags: rust, macros

The following rust code does not compile because of the macro error

```
error: local ambiguity: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs stmt ('s') or 1 other option.
```

macro A is fine. Macro B shows the error.

```
macro_rules! A {
    ($x: ident, $($s: stmt)*) => {
        println!("hello");
    };
}

macro_rules! B {
    ($x: ident, $($s: stmt)*; $e: expr) => {
        println!("hello");
    };
}

fn main() {
    A![my_name, let x=5];
    B![my_name, let x=5; 5];
}
```

This minimal reproducible example in B is exactly what I need. I want the macro to accept multiple let statements and terminate by some other expression.

What is the ambiguity that is being referred to?

Is there a way around it?

Of those tokens accepted after statement fragments I have tried several combinations yet none appear to make a difference. Neither does swapping the statement with a token tree.

Comment: Do you only expect `let` statements in `s`?

Comment: @mcarton you mean for example `5;` ?

Comment: @mcarton yes I only expect arbitrary variable bindings

Comment: `5;` is a statement (containing an expression) but not an expression. `if foo { 42 } else { 31 }` doesn't have a semi-column and really can be both a statement and an expression.

Comment: @mcarton okay great. that makes sense. that answers the first part of my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expressions are statements, so `$($s: stmt)*; $e: expr` is ambiguous because the compiler can't decide between using `s` or `e` when it encounters one.

Since you only expect bindings, you can easily expand them yourself:

```rust
macro_rules! A {
    ($x: ident, $($s: stmt)*) => {
        println!("hello");
    };
}

macro_rules! B {
    ($x: ident, $(let $p:pat = $v:expr)*; $e: expr) => {
        $(let $p = $v);*
        println!("hello: {}", $e);
    };
}

fn main() {
    A![my_name, let x=5];
    B![my_name, let x=5; x+2];
}
```

Note that this doesn't support including types in the binding (`let a: i32 = 42;`) because `pat` can't be followed by `:`.

Comment: I see. I did try expanding them myself and began getting that the tokens I was trying for the type were not allowed. I had put your `$p` as an identifier in mine. what difference might that have?

Comment: using an identifier instead of a pattern seems to work well in my testing

Comment: All identifiers are patterns, but patterns are more general. Eg. `let (a, b) = (1, 2);` works because `let` takes a pattern not an identifier.

Comment: I've marked you for the answer. Can you add your last comment to your answer? I think it's relevant.